# Prove that for $X\geq 0$ $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X>k)\leq E[X]\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X>k)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Prove that for $X\geq0$ :$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X>k)\leq E[X]\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X>k)$

I know that :

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X\geq k)=E[X]$ So I get:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X>k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X\geq k) \leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X>k)$ Then:
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X>k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X\geq k) \leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X>k-1)$  Then:
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-F(k))\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-F(k-)) \leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1-F(k-1)$ Which implies that :
$1-F(k)\leq 1-F(k-)\leq1-F(k-1)$ Which implies that:
$F(k)\leq F(k-)\leq F(k-1)$ and is true for any $F(k)$ Is it a solid proof? Where should I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
E(X) &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{\{k-1< X \leq k\}} X dP \\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k P(k-1< X \leq k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \Big[P(X > k-1) - P(X > k) \Big]\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big[k P(X > k-1) - k P(X > k)\Big]\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\Big[(k-1+1) P(X > k-1) - k P(X > k)\Big]\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg[\sum_{k=1}^n P(X > k-1) - nP(X > n)\bigg]\\
&\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n P(X > k-1)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X > k-1)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X > k).
\end{align*}
The other side is similar.

Comment: Revised to take the convergence problem into consideration.